# Как разместить неполный полукруг с тенью под полупрозрачным элементом?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть блок с лого `png` с прозрачностью и тенью. Мне нужно разместить под ним неполный полукруг с тенью так, чтобы он не перекрывал основной лого и тень у него не обрезалась.

2 примера ниже, которые я хочу совместить:

**в первом** - полукруг такой, который нужен, но у него обрезается тень снизу , а если убираем `overflow:hidden;`, то верхняя часть перекрывает само лого. `z-index` проблема не решается, т.к. лого имеет прозрачность

**второй пример** - правильная тень на псевдоэлементе, но форма не та, т.к. полукруг полный и в текущем виде больше похоже на яйцо.

```css
body {
  background-color: #6f959a;
}

.block {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 23px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 207px;
  left: 0;
}

.new {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
}

.new:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 23px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

#second:after {
  content: "";
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 207px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 100% 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 23px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 14px 23px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://idea.usaid.gov/assets/logo.dffa213d497aa2314a77ed16badccd61.png">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="new"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block" id="second">
  <img src="https://idea.usaid.gov/assets/logo.dffa213d497aa2314a77ed16badccd61.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заверните лого в обёртку, которая будет выше по z-index чем полукруг. У вас получится область с прямоугольной тенью, полукруг и сверху всего этого белый прямоугольник, который скроет верхнюю часть тени полукруга.

```css
body {
  background-color: #6f959a;
}

.block {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 23px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  position: relative;
}

.block:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -80px;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 100% 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 23px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://idea.usaid.gov/assets/logo.dffa213d497aa2314a77ed16badccd61.png">
  </div>
</div>
```